# Linq data base insertion error

Tags: c#, database, linq

So i have the following method:

```
  public void dataSchreiben(Messdaten data)
    {
        try
        {
            var ctxMess = new MessdatenDataContext();
            var messSchreiben = new Messdaten()
            {

                stromschwSoll = data.stromschwSoll,  
                stromscwIst = data.stromscwIst, 

                stromMaxSoll = data.stromMaxSoll, 
                stromIst = data.stromIst,       

                drehzahl = data.drehzahl,       

                sollwerDrehmMaxon = data.sollwerDrehmMaxon,
                istwertDrehmMaxonDR1 = data.istwertDrehmMaxonDR1,
                istwertDrehmMaxonDR2 = data.istwertDrehmMaxonDR2,

                rueckdrehmSollImLauf = data.rueckdrehmSollImLauf,
                ruedrehmIstImLaufDR1 = data.ruedrehmIstImLaufDR1,
                ruedrehmIstImLaufDR2 = data.ruedrehmIstImLaufDR2,

                ruedrehmSollLosbrechen = data.ruedrehmSollLosbrechen,
                ruedrehmIstLosbrDR1 = data.ruedrehmIstLosbrDR1,
                ruedrehmIstLosbrDR2 = data.ruedrehmIstLosbrDR2,

                sollwVerdrspGetriebe = data.sollwVerdrspGetriebe,
                istwVerdrspGetriebe = data.istwVerdrspGetriebe,

                sollVerdrehspGeber = data.sollVerdrehspGeber,
                istwVerdrehspGeber = data.istwVerdrehspGeber,

                serialNummer = "Succes" 


            };
            ctxMess.Messdaten.InsertAllOnSubmit(messSchreiben);
            try
            {
                ctxMess.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                ctxMess.SubmitChanges();
            }

        }catch {
            MessageBox.Show("Schreiben error !", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

I have a database, that contains 21 fields(an index autoincremetable, and a timestamp).Messdaten data is a structure containing the fields below.The InsertAllOnSubmit gives back this error:

> the type arguments of System.Data.Linq 
>   InsertAllOnSubmit  (System.Collections.IEnumerable
>   ) -. methods can not be derived by inference from the
>   syntax. Enter the type arguments explicitly

Also, my variables are of double type, while in the database they are saved as float. Could this generate the problem or is it something else?
I searched on google, but no solution came up.

```
public struct Messdaten                 //a structure containing all the elements of the measurements
    {

        public double stromschwSoll;
        public double stromscwIst;

        public double stromMaxSoll;
        public double stromIst;

        public double drehzahl;

        public double sollwerDrehmMaxon;
        public double istwertDrehmMaxonDR1;
        public double istwertDrehmMaxonDR2;

        public double rueckdrehmSollImLauf;
        public double ruedrehmIstImLaufDR1;
        public double ruedrehmIstImLaufDR2;

        public double ruedrehmSollLosbrechen;
        public double ruedrehmIstLosbrDR1;
        public double ruedrehmIstLosbrDR2;

        public double sollwVerdrspGetriebe;
        public double istwVerdrspGetriebe;

        public double sollVerdrehspGeber;
        public double istwVerdrehspGeber;

        public string serialNummer;
    }
    public Messdaten aktMessung;
```

And the database declaration:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Messdaten")]
public partial class Messdaten : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _Index;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _TimeStamp;

    private System.Nullable<double> _StromschwSollLastlos;

    private System.Nullable<double> _StromschwIstLastlos;

    private System.Nullable<double> _StromMaxSollLastlos;

    private System.Nullable<double> _StromMaxIstLastlos;

    private System.Nullable<double> _DrehzahlMaxonmotor;

    private System.Nullable<double> _SollwertDrehmMaxon;

    private System.Nullable<double> _IstwertDrehmMaxonDR1;

    private System.Nullable<double> _IstwertDrehmMaxonDR2;

    private System.Nullable<double> _RueckdrehmSollImLauf;

    private System.Nullable<double> _RuedrehmIstImLaufDR1;

    private System.Nullable<double> _RuedrehmIstImLaufDR2;

    private System.Nullable<double> _RuedrehmSollLosbrechen;

    private System.Nullable<double> _RuedrehmIstLosbrDR1;

    private System.Nullable<double> _RuedrehmIstLosbrDR2;

    private System.Nullable<double> _SollwVerdrspGetriebe;

    private System.Nullable<double> _IstwVerdrspGetriebe;

    private System.Nullable<double> _SollVerdrehspGeber;

    private System.Nullable<double> _IstwVerdrehspGeber;

    private string _SerialNummer;
```

Errors:
the best match for the overloaded System.Data.Linq.Table  InsertOnSubmit (STW_PruefStand.Messdaten -. has not some invalid method

1 - argument: can not convert from 'STW_PruefStand.Form1.Messdaten "in" "STW_PruefStand.Messdaten"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InsertAllOnSubmit` is used for collections of objects to be inserted in the DB. Here you are dealing with just one object, so the correct method to use is `InsertOnSubmit`:

```
ctxMess.Messdaten.InsertOnSubmit(messSchreiben);
```

**Update.** After question update, new problem seems to be related to the naming. Both struct and context class have names `Messdaten`, which is misleading. For instance, this line:

```
var messSchreiben = new Messdaten()
```

instantiates object of type `STW_PruefStand.Form1.Messdaten` (the struct), while according to the logic of the method it should be context class. Try specifying the namespace explicitly:

```
var messSchreiben = new STW_PruefStand.Messdaten()
{
...
```

Comment: Yes, this did solve part of the problem, but now i get the following error: the best match for the overloaded System.Data.Linq.Table <Project.MeasuredData> InsertOnSubmit (Project.MeasuredData) -. method has not some invalid arguments ... as i said except the last SerialNummer variable, which is string, they are all doubles...and in the db, they are all float and the SerialNummer is a nChar...could the problem be coming from here?

Comment: @BoraBogdan, is it the same code that shows the error? Code in the question deals with `Messdaten` class, while here you are talking about `MeasuredData`.

Comment: yes, MeasureData refers to the db table in which the data should be inserted..the error is given by the same InsertOnSubmit line

Comment: @BoraBogdan, oh, seems like I see the problem now. `ctxMess.Messdaten` is a table of `Project.MeasuredData` objects, while you are trying to insert object of type `Messdaten`. Most likely you need to change the way you are constructing object for insert, like this: `var messSchreiben = new Project.MeasuredData`. Does it make sense?

Comment: @BoraBogdan, what is the size of the nChar? why are you using nChar? Also, you are catching an exception in the first **SubmitChanges()**, writing this to console, and attempting **SubmitChanges()** again? This seems confusing.

Comment: @Andrei, yes, Messdaten is a struct that contains all the variables to be inserted in the database. But var messSchreiben = new STW_PruefStand.Messdaten (i only translated to the original name, as i program in another language, STW_Pruefstand is the project namespace, and Messdaten is the structure) didn't solve anything... also this error appears: the system adds an entity with the status of a pending insert

Comment: @BoraBogdan, again, for insert you should use the class that is `ctxMess.Messdaten` typed with. Judging from the error you have posted above, this is `Project.MeasuredData`, precisely, without any need for translation.

Comment: yes i tried your solution, but it doesn't change anything. i stood the last 20 minutes since your comment trying to be sure that's not the issue.

Comment: @BoraBogdan, then I believe we should dig deeper. Could you please update the post with the actual code? Also it would be great to see `MessdatenDataContext.Messdaten` declaration.

Comment: Updated, with the structure of Messdaten(the struct) and the dbtable Messdaten. Now i see that the db table and the struct have the same name..

Comment: Thanks, another error dissapeared, the last one standing being this : Members, such as fields or methods, for example, can not be included directly in namespace

Comment: @BoraBogdan, at what line?

Comment: it doesn't mention...i just tracked this type of error on google, and it seems related to the db table and app property of build process(buildvorgang in german, hope google translate did a good job)..

Comment: @BoraBogdan, I believe it has to do with this line `public Messdaten aktMessung;` (at the very bottom of your struct listing). It does look like member declaration without any class.

Comment: aktMessung is the Messdaten strucute variable used across the rest of the application..by different methods Messdaten is filled with the data...and then when aktMessung has all necessary data...i call the method like this dataSchreiben(aktMessung);

Comment: @BoraBogdan, this is impossible in C# to have some global variable used all across the application. Everything must be a member of a class. You should remove this declaration (cause it is the source of the last error) and consider a different approach.

Comment: It is a member of the public partial class Form1 : Form.. and it is used only inside.

Comment: @BoraBogdan, then I must admit I have no idea where this last error comes from. Obviously there is an invalid declaration somewhere in the source code. But if `aktMessung` is declared inside the class, everything is OK with the code you've posted, which means that error is elsewhere. However Visual Studio (or the IDE you are using) should be able to highlight this problem.

Comment: Solved the problem yesterday, i had a stupid error. Both my db table and structure were named Messdaten, and instead of taking the db table..the program was taking the strucure. Thanks a lot for the errors you helped me solve along the way !

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `InsertOnSubmit()`, since you are only adding **one object**.

See **MSDN** links [InsertOnSubmit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) & [InsertAllOnSubmit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763488.aspx) for differences.